# How i can change header button (sign in to log in) in magento 2 ? and which file i can change?

Tags: magento2, theme, header

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Which file i can change .xml or .phtml file 
Sign in to Log in

where the location of files....

Answer (score 6):

The simple way is to add default text with your text into `app/design/frontend/Custom/default/i18n/en_US.csv`

like

```
"Sign In","Login"
```

clear cache after that

```
php bin/magento cache:clean && php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: i added to layout folder but not changing...

Comment: you don't need to do anything with layout folder, create en_US.csv into i18n folder if not there in your custom theme

Comment: i18n floder not in my custom theme

Comment: Ok then you should create there

Comment: it's working how.....

Comment: ok great accept answer if its working

Comment: Thank you ....
i want to know how it's working ....

Comment: i18n/en_US.csv file is especially for translate word or line from one language to another (en_US is for english to english), in your case we give English word with English just change the text

Comment: can i add Any text in header

Comment: Yes why not, you can

Comment: how ...
if i add  any text to that csv file 
what happen

Comment: I added text but not showing in header ...

"Sign In","Login" 
"Contact us"

Answer (score 2):

You need to change `getLabel()` function in `\Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink`

1. Create the di.xml file in your custom module. Add the following :

`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink" type="Custom\Module\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink" />
</config>`

2. Create `AuthorizationLink.php` under `Custom\Module\Block\Account\` and add the following :

`<?php
namespace Custom\Module\Block\Account;
class AuthorizationLink extends \Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink
{
    public function getLabel()
    {
        return $this->isLoggedIn() ? __('Sign Out') : __('Log In');
    }
}`

Run setup upgrade command and check the result. It's done.

Comment: \Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink  this path not in my app\design

Comment: It will not be in app/design. Start doing from point 1.

Comment: That problem is solved ...
How i can add Text in header

Comment: By point number 2.

Comment: pub/static or vendor  folder

Comment: which method i use to print the "contact us"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the 'create account' label with XML the code you have to paste

**Go to app/design/frontend/vendor/module/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml**

and place below code

```
<referenceBlock name="register-link">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Resiter Account</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
```

[image]